# function returning 0

Tags: functions, summation

Why is my function returning 0?

```
In[95]:= n = 25;
r[x_, y_] = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
\[Theta][x_, y_] = ArcTan[x, y];
f[y] = Piecewise[{{100, 0 <= y <= 1}, {0, -1 <= y <= 0}}];

In[109]:= 
c = Table[(2*l + 1)/2*
    Integrate[f[y]*LegendreP[l, 0, y], {y, -1, 1}], {l, 0, n}];

In[100]:= 
T[x_, y_] = 
 Parallelize[
  Sum[c[[n]]*r[x, y]^l*LegendreP[l, 0, Cos[\[Theta][x, y]]], {l, 0, 
    n}]]

Out[100]= 0
```

I don't understand why `T[x,y]` is returning only 0.

---

**Edit 2:**

So if I start `l` from 1 and add in `c[[0]]` manual to the sum the code works but something is still going wrong.

The top of northern hemisphere is supposed to be held at 100 and the southern hemisphere is supposed to be held at 0.

When I plot this for different n, the temperature distribution switches to 100 on the top to 100 on the bottom and similarly for 0.

And the 100 on the top is always chopped out.

This is n = 25 and n = 23, respectively.

```
DensityPlot[T[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

[image]

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Why is 100 chopped off, why is it flipping position at different n, and why do I have to add in `c[[0]]` instead of letting it integrate l = 0 and summing at l = 0?

If n is too large, then the image is:

[image]

Edit 3:

Here is the code I am using.  Try n = 25, n = 35, and n = 50 to see what happens.

```
n = 35;
r[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
\[Theta][x_, y_] := ArcTan[y, x];
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{100, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, -1 <= x <= 0}}];

c = Table[(2*l + 1)/2*
    Integrate[f[x]*LegendreP[l, 0, x], {x, -1, 1}], {l, 1, n}];

T[x_, y_] = 
  50 + Sum[c[[n]]*r[x, y]^l*LegendreP[l, 0, Cos[\[Theta][x, y]]], {l, 
     0, n}];

Plot3D[T[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
 PlotRange -> All]

DensityPlot[T[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Regarding the first part, you use `c[[n]]` which happens to be zero; maybe you meant to use `c[[l]]` in the summation. Also you need to define `f[y_]` with an underscore.

Comment: Adding to b's comment you should define your functions like this `f[x_] := r.h.s`. As you can see you have omitted the `:`.

Comment: good practice, but it should work since he only uses f with a literal y argument.

Comment: i dont know if it pertains to the problem, but this seems a poor use of parallelize -- the integration is already done when you define c. If anything you should use paralletable on the c definition..

Comment: The white parts are due to plot range clipping.  Set the option `PlotRange -> All`.  `T` will be zero for odd `n > 1` because `c[[n]]` equals zero.  See b.gatessucks' comment above.

Comment: @b.gatessucks using `c[[l]]` causes one c to be labelled list whereas this doesn't occur with `c[[n]]`.  Also, following everyone advice yields the last image in post so nothing has improved.

Comment: @MichaelE2 the plot doesn't work for `n = 50` but it works for 25.  At `n = 35`, the heat map switches to 100 at the bottom.  Also, the 100 should be the northern hemisphere not just the tip and 0 should be the southern hemisphere whereas it appears to be every where but the northern tip when n = 25.

Comment: f[y]='something involving y' will not work (as expected) in Table[something involving f[y],{y,some range}] as the y inside table is not the global symbol y.  Try f[y] = 4 and Table[f[y], {y, 1, 3}] and you get {f[1], f[2], f[3]} not {4, 4, 4}.  You do need f[y_]= 'something involving y' or more likely f[y_]:= 'something involving y'.

Comment: @Yamareth I have no idea what you are trying to say with you comment, sorry.

Comment: f[y] creates a definition of f specific to the exact symbol y. Table[f[y], {y,-1,1}] looks like its using the same symbol but infact it will be a temporary symbol like y$001 created on the fly by Mathemtica and only used within that expression.

Comment: Sometimes that is what you mean but usually you want something like f[y_]:=y^2 which means whatever I put inside f[?] call that y and evaluate the expression on the right using that for the value of y.  The underscore is very important.

Comment: @Ymareth that was mentioned by other commentators.  I have also added an edit 3 which shows the other issue at hand.

Comment: The reason it works now for `n = 35` but not for `n = 50` is still the same.  It is a property of the `LegendreP` function that the integral you use to define the coefficients `c` is zero when the order `l` is even. In the first version, the order of part `n` was `l == n - 1`.  In edit three, part `n` now corresponds to order `l == n`. So now all the `c[[n]]` are zero for even `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I think you probably want:

```
n = 50;
r[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
θ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[y, x];
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{100, 0 <= x <= 1}, {0, -1 <= x <= 0}}];

c = Table[(2 * l + 1) / 2 * Integrate[f[x]*LegendreP[l, 0, x], {x, -1, 1}], {l, 0, n}];

T[x_, y_] = Sum[c[[1 + l]] * r[x, y]^l * LegendreP[l, 0, Cos[θ[x, y]]], {l, 0, n}];
```

Then:

```
Plot3D[T[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
DensityPlot[T[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the sake of speed, consider using `Dot` and the listability of `Power` and `LegendreP`:

```
T2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
  With[{r0 = r[x, y]}, c.(r0^Range[0, n]*LegendreP[Range[0, n], 0, y/r0])];
```

It's more than twice as fast:

```
DensityPlot[T[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
  PlotRange -> All] // AbsoluteTiming
DensityPlot[T2[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 0 < x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
  PlotRange -> All] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can also compute a formula for the coefficients (it takes about 0.5 sec.):

```
coeff[l_] = (2*l + 1) / 2 * Integrate[f[x] * LegendreP[l, 0, x], {x, -1, 1}]
(* (25 (1 + 2 l) Sqrt[π])/(Gamma[1 - l/2] Gamma[(3 + l)/2]) *)
```

Then computing `c` can be quite fast:

```
n = 100;
c = Table[(2*l + 1)/ 2 * Integrate[f[x] * LegendreP[l, 0, x], {x, -1, 1}], {l, 0, n}]; //
      AbsoluteTiming
c = coeff /@ Range[0, n]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {8.634086, Null} *)
(* {0.002338, Null} *)
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I was striving for.  Is it possible to plot a 3D sphere with this correct gradient as well?

Comment: @dustin Forgive me, but I can't figure out what gradient you're referring to or how it would map onto a sphere.  But I'm pretty sure that if you know the mathematical formulation, then it will be possible to do.

Comment: I mean since this a solution to Laplace on sphere can the sphere with the heat map be plotted?

Comment: Also, is there a way to speed up the finding of c?  When I increase n, the calculation of c slows down immensely.

Comment: @dustin Yes, there's a formula for `c`.  See edit.  I would have to work out the gradient, which I don't have time to do just now.  (If it's obvious, then I simply am blanking on it. :)  Perhaps you should ask that as a separate question.  It would help to get answers if you could include formulas for the gradient.

Comment: @dustin ParallelTable speed it up quit a lot (Michaels approach wont always work for a general not-piecewise-constant f..). If you retain only floating values that helps as well.. 'ParallelTable[ ... Integrate[] //N ]'