# Want more vibrant colors in plots

Tags: plotting, color

Is it possible to create plots that have vibrant colors like those I create in Python?

For instance, take this thread [function returning 0](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33492/function-returning-0) where I used rainbow and here is the temperature gradient:
[image]

Now here is a heat map I created in Python for comparison.
[image]

Comment: If you don't like _Mathematica_'s colors, you just need to recreate the colormap used by python. In this case, it is the "jet" colormap, which you can implement as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9321152). While it is ubiquitous in science/engineering, the jet colormap is one of the worst when it comes to showing variation in the data.

Comment: @belisarius I used rainbow in the linked post and in this post I used TemperatureMap.

Comment: @rm-rf so that answer you linked will add jet to the Mathematica or just in the instances it is saved in?

Comment: @rm-rf also, I just need to add: `jet[u_?NumericQ] := Blend[
        {{0, RGBColor[0, 0, 9/16]}, {1/9, Blue}, {23/63, Cyan}, {13/21, Yellow},
         {47/63, Orange}, {55/63, Red}, {1, RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}}, 
                          u]` and then I can do `colorfunction->"jet"`?

Comment: @dustin `ColorFunction -> jet`

Comment: @rm-rf thanks.  Do you want me to delete this post or not since the answer is on SO?

Comment: Post it as an answer here.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251872/is-there-a-better-color-scale-than-the-rainbow-colormap

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote to discourage garish graph makers. :)

Comment: So do we close this as a duplicate or transwer some of the answers form SO to MMA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to implement your own colour function and use it.  There's an implementation of the MATLAB `jet` colour function in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321152).  It is very similar to the example you posted.