# Beautiful Temperature Map

Tags: plotting, color, plot-themes

Simple Question:
I want to create beautiful density plots like those on [a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zernike_polynomials#/media/File:Zernike_polynomials2.png):

[image]

Mathematica has a lot of built-in color functions but none of them is as good as Wikipedia's. I tried "Rainbow", "DarkRainbow", Hue, "TemperatureMap" and "ThermometerColors" so far.

I plot density plots of Zernike Polynomials with ["Zernike.m" package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4483/).
The code I use is as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
<< "Zernike.m"
Table[DensityPlot[
  Zernike[i, Norm[{x, y}], ArcTan[x, y]], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 
  PlotRange -> All, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True], {i, 1, 10}]
```

And the result I'm not satisfied is as follows:
[image: TemperatureMap]

How can I use a color function or create a color function like the one on the Wikipedia? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The color map you want is the jet color theme used by Matlab I think, and in my opinion it should be avoided if the goal is to convey information, [see here for discussion](http://mycarta.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/the-rainbow-is-dead-long-live-the-rainbow-series-outline/). But you can define the color map using the code here:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64514/9490

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33511/9490

Comment: Why do you have `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` and `ColorFunctionScaling -> True` in your options?  Part of the problem is that the default range for color functions is between 0 and 1;  it looks like your polynomials have negative values in some regions (hence the solid blue) and values greater than +1 in others (the solid red regions.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the built-in color schemes [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ColorSchemes.html) are not good for you, you can write your own.

See for example a scheme that I often use:

```
scheme = (Blend[{RGBColor[0.02, 1, 1], RGBColor[0, 0.48, 1], RGBColor[
 0, 0, 0.73], Black, RGBColor[0.6, 0.22, 0], RGBColor[1, 0.55, 0],
  White}, Rescale[#1, {-1, 1}]] &);

BarLegend[{scheme[#] &, {-1, 1}}]
```

> [image]

You can change the colours of the scheme to obtain the combination you like the most.

See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154269/plotrange-in-densityplot) question I asked some time ago for some useful details!